# nginx + Rails 3.1 + Cloudfront assets subdirectories 404 missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Rails 3.1 asset pipeline which is served using a custom origin Cloudfront CDN.

This is what I have written in my nginx.conf to serve the assets in gzip and for caching:

```
                location ^~ /assets/ {
                    allow all;
                    gzip_http_version 1.0;
                    gzip_static on;
                    expires 365d;
                    add_header Last-Modified "";
                    add_header ETAg "";
                    add_header Cache-Control public;
            }
```

The problem is that subdirectories e.g. /background/ in my images asset folder have their items missing with 404s.

When I disable the nginx location config above the problem goes away. How do I configure nginx properly to serve the assets in the subdirectories?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for taking awhile to get back. But yeah I tried it today and it works fine! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /opt/appname/public; # or whatever the path is to your app's public folder
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_static on;
    access_log off;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
}
```